# Declare variable in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, variable-declaration

I have problem with declare variable in stored procedure. I used MySQL. My example code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `name`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE varname INT;

    SELECT  * FROM `table` INTO var;
END
```

MySQL returns error:

> error 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near '' at line 3

Comment: Doesn't matter, becouse It's problem with `` . I change var name in first post.

Answer (score 4):

When you have multiple statements in a procedure you have to change the delimiter. Otherwise MySQL thinks that the procedure declaration is finished after the first statement.

Here's an example that works. And btw, `var` is **not** a reserved keyword like others are trying to tell you.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE var INT;
    SELECT 1 INTO var;
    SELECT var;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL test();
+------+
| var  |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I will repost my answer, to ensure I was not wrong. The events went different way .

Answer (score 2):

var is a ***reserved*** key word

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE  var2 INT;
    // Do something
END;
```

---

***Update*** :

I saw MAriaDB in the error , the correct way to declare variable in MariaDB is

```
SET @var = 0;
```

You should tag your question with the correct keywords

Comment: @fancyPants : Can you please elaborate your comment, I know its less explanatory but whats your view. Note : updating about `` ;)